# Adding video to a Wordpress website

Tags: videos, hosting, video-player

I have just configured a new Wordpress install, and everything is working correctly. The only difference between this site and the other Wordpress sites that I run is this one is going to be heavily video based. In each blog post, I want at least one video to go along with the text.

Now I could host my videos with YouTube or Vimeo, but I'm worried that my content might break their rules, so I was thinking of hosting the videos myself on my server (I use Linode and could quite easily use Linode block storage to store all of the videos). Hosting the videos myself gives me a lot more flexibility in what I can do in my videos, but I was wondering if there was a plugin or something that helped to automate the whole process?

I want to be able to upload videos directly from within the Wordpress admin panel, but if that is not possible, then I could use SCP to upload them. As long as I can store them on a separate partition, I should be OK as the base specifications of my VPS are quite low.

If anyone has any advice, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I don't know what kind of videos you are including that would break the rules of these websites (especially Vimeo, I think they are pretty lenient on what you can upload there) but in general, I would usually advise against hosting your own videos.

Websites like YouTube and Vimeo, who are specialized in this kind of thing, are usually faster and have a whole lot of infrastructure in place to serve videos as quickly as possible, even as embeds on other sites. So, unless you have a super fast server or the knowledge to optimize it for videos, I would usually vote for embeds.

I hear a lot of good stuff about Vimeo Pro in this area. You might want to check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll look into a Vimeo pro plan in that case. I guess I can always keep my videos backed up in-case anything happens to the hosted ones on Vimeo and move to self-hosting them.

Comment: Absolutely. Let me know how it goes!